# Access randomly drops decimals when inserting from txt file

Tags: sql, csv

I have a number of .csv files in the following format with example data listed:

```
    ID,Lat,Long
    1,-43.76120167,158.0299917
    2,-43.76119833,158.03
    3,-43.7612,158.0299983
    4,-43.76120167,158.0299967
```

The values change from file to file, but they're always the same format and similar amounts. What you see above is exactly how it shows up in the .csv file (when opened with a texpad/notepad not in Excel - so we can eliminate any Excel problems now).

However, when I run the following INSERT statement as an Access SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT * FROM [Text;Database=C:\;Hdr=Yes].[ImportFile.csv];
```

This is what shows up in my Access database table:

```
    ID,Lat,Long
    1,-43,158
    2,-43,158
    3,-43,158
    4,-43,158
```

Now, I know what you're thinking. Let me just say that my table design in Access is set up such that ID is a Number/Long Integer, and both of my Lat and Long fields are set up as Number/Double with 4 Decimal Places. I've double checked this a million times and it can be confirmed because not all input files share this problem.

This is what is troubling me... where are all the digits after my decimal point going? I need to have them.

What confuses me even more is that some files read just fine and the decimal points stay in there just fine... same table, same insert query. Every file is generated from the same source and formatted the same for what it's worth.

However, if I fire up Access itself and run the import from text file wizard, the values end up just fine. Access automatically makes the field a double with auto decimals (I have also tried using auto decimals in my desired table, to no avail).

Anyone have any idea what is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Access are you using? That query works properly for  me. Are your fields, or is your default data type an integer?

Comment: Hi Arun, the Jet engine was assigning it's own data types based on the first 16(?) records or so. In the case of these random files with problems, the first 16 records were 0 instead of 0.0. Doesn't quite make sense as they should have been null to begin with but I think that's a different problem with my code somewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is well known problem.

The Jet database engine determines the data types from data source.  One of solutions is to use/create Schema.ini file.
Also, keep in mind that, in order to determine data type for columns, only first few rows are scanned.

For more info, please see [here](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/jet-incorrect-data-type-issues)

Comment: Sorry Kenan, I should have mentioned... the table I am inserting to is already created, with the correct data types (Number - Double - 4 decimal places).

Comment: It's not a problem with a table in Access, it's a problem how Jet engine "understand" csv file. Please read a link from my answer.

Comment: Hi Kenan, thanks for your help. Your post led me down the right path. Indeed the Jet Engine was assigning a data type regardless of what was set in the Access table. I think the solutions mentioned in your link would work, but for me I just hardcoded in a solution into my VB (finding and replacing 0s generated from null fields with 0.0s). Thanks!